# Fresh Ubuntu user, watching video with firefox crushes my system

Tags: firefox

this incident happent several times today, i am trying to watch some videos from udemy with my ubuntu firefox. It randomly stucks and whole system stops. Only thing to do is restarting pc by pressing shutdown button. Why would this happen? I'll reinstall firefox and hope it helps.

Thanks